# In topology what is meant by a square and a circle?

Tags: general-topology

When you have terms such as square or circle in topology does it mean only the boundary of the object or the interior space also?

Comment: I'd say the same meaning they have in elementary geometry: square is the plane region and circle is the boundary of the disk.

Comment: If not specified, most probably the boundaries only.

Comment: @Gae.S. Square can also be used to represent the interior, i.e., the unit square. For some reason, geometry textbooks I've used refer to the filled square as a unit square, but just the boundary of a circle as the unit circle

Comment: @DonThousand I mean the region bounded by the polygonal line (with or without boundary must be specified).

Comment: Please provide some context: what examples of the usage of the words "square" and "circle" are you looking at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boundaries are topologically the same, and can be called “circle” or $\Bbb S^1$. The two-dimensional area (so with inside area too) is called a “disk” (or $\Bbb D^2$, topologically the same as a filled square). Product sets like $[0,1] \times [2,3]$ are called “rectangle” in the product topology, ofttimes. That the “lengths” are equal in this case is irrelevant in topology.